# How can I remove trailing characters from a string using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, cut

How can I remove the last *n* characters from a particular string using shell script?

This is my input:

```
ssl01:49188,,,
ssl01:49188,
ssl01:49188,,,,,
ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188,,,,,
ssl01:49188,abcf999:49188,,,,,
```

The output should be in the following format:

```
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188
ssl01:49188,abcf999:49188
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To answer the title of you question with specifies **cutting last n character in a string**, you can use the substring extraction feature in Bash.

```
me@home$ A="123456"
me@home$ echo ${A:0:-2}  # remove last 2 chars
1234
```

However, based on your examples you appear to want to **remove all trailing commas**, in which case you could use `sed 's/,*$//'`.

```
me@home$ echo "ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188,,,,," | sed 's/,*$//'
ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188
```

or, for a purely Bash solution, you could use substring removal:

```
me@home$ X="ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188,,,,,"
me@home$ shopt -s extglob
me@home$ echo ${X%%+(,)}
ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188
```

I would use the `sed` approach if the transformation needs to be applied to a whole file, and the bash substring removal approach if the target string is already in a bash variable.

Comment: Please note that the first solution only works for newer versions of Bash (>= 4.2-alpha).

Comment: for older versions: use #item to get length of the string, so if you are trying to remove last n chars, do it like item="abcdefgh" echo ${item:0:${#item}-n};

Comment: I know this is trivial, but figured I would state it here because it tripped me up.  Make sure you put the semi-colon on the end just like rivu has it!  I forgot the semi-colon and got all sorts of errors!

Comment: @user972276: There is no need for a semicolon at the _end_, but you do need semicolons to _separate_ multiple commands on a single line. rivu's full Bash 3.x example on a single line is therefore: `n=2; item='abcdefgh'; echo "${item:0:${#item}-n}"`

Answer (score 12):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/,\+$//' file
```

Comment: That works well, but only with _GNU_ `sed`. A POSIX-compliant reformulation is `sed 's/,\{1,\}//'`. A version that works with both GNU and BSD/OSX `sed`: `sed -E 's/,+//'`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to remove those unnecessary `,`'s

```
sed 's/,,//g;s/\,$//g' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
ssl01:49188,,,
ssl01:49188,
ssl01:49188,,,,,
ssl01:49188,,,
ssl01:49188,
ssl01:49188,,,,,
ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188,,,,,
ssl01:49188,abcf999:49188,,,,,
> sed 's/,,//g;s/\,$//g' temp
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188
ssl01:49188,ssl999999:49188
ssl01:49188,abcf999:49188
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/,,*$//g' file
```